# Spark scala create multiple columns from array column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Creating a multiple columns from array column

**Dataframe**

```
Car name |  details
Toyota   | [[year,2000],[price,20000]]
Audi     | [[mpg,22]]
```

**Expected dataframe**

```
Car name | year | price | mpg
Toyota   | 2000 | 20000 | null
Audi     | null | null | 22
```

Comment: is (year, 2000) of type tuple or map ?
can you print the schema of the dataframe ?

Comment: Since your question is not related to the spark-streaming, I discard that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

Let's define the data

```
scala> val carsDF = Seq(("toyota",Array(("year", 2000), ("price", 100000))), ("Audi", Array(("mpg", 22)))).toDF("car", "details")
carsDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [car: string, details: array<struct<_1:string,_2:int>>]

scala> carsDF.show(false)
+------+-----------------------------+
|car   |details                      |
+------+-----------------------------+
|toyota|[[year,2000], [price,100000]]|
|Audi  |[[mpg,22]]                   |
+------+-----------------------------+
```

Splitting the data & accessing the values in the data

```
scala> carsDF.withColumn("split", explode($"details")).withColumn("col", $"split"("_1")).withColumn("val", $"split"("_2")).select("car", "col", "val").show
+------+-----+------+
|   car|  col|   val|
+------+-----+------+
|toyota| year|  2000|
|toyota|price|100000|
|  Audi|  mpg|    22|
+------+-----+------+
```

Define the list of columns that are required

```
scala> val colNames = Seq("mpg", "price", "year", "dummy")
colNames: Seq[String] = List(mpg, price, year, dummy)
```

Use pivoting on the above defined column names gives required output.
By giving new column names in the sequence makes it a single point input

```
scala> weDF.groupBy("car").pivot("col", colNames).agg(avg($"val")).show
+------+----+--------+------+-----+
|   car| mpg|   price|  year|dummy|
+------+----+--------+------+-----+
|toyota|null|100000.0|2000.0| null|
|  Audi|22.0|    null|  null| null|
+------+----+--------+------+-----+
```

This seems more elegant & easy way to achieve the output

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like that

```
import org.apache.spark.functions.col
val df: DataFrame = Seq(
  ("toyota",Array(("year", 2000), ("price", 100000))),
  ("toyota",Array(("year", 2001)))
).toDF("car", "details")

 +------+-------------------------------+
 |car   |details                        |
 +------+-------------------------------+
 |toyota|[[year, 2000], [price, 100000]]|
 |toyota|[[year, 2001]]                 |
 +------+-------------------------------+

val newdf = df
  .withColumn("year", when(col("details")(0)("_1") === lit("year"), col("details")(0)("_2")).otherwise(col("details")(1)("_2")))
  .withColumn("price", when(col("details")(0)("_1") === lit("price"), col("details")(0)("_2")).otherwise(col("details")(1)("_2")))
  .drop("details")

newdf.show()
  +------+----+------+
  |   car|year| price|
  +------+----+------+
  |toyota|2000|100000|     
  |toyota|2001|  null|
  +------+----+------+
```

Comment: How can  i do if year and price element are not in order.

Comment: you can add a when otherwise test inside the withColumn to see if the value is year or price

Comment: Hi @firsni , how can I make it dynamic I updated the question .

Comment: you need to have a Map instead of an array to make it dynamic